# Separating items of counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, counter

```
with open('data2.csv','r') as data:
    reader = csv.DictReader(data)
    counter = Counter()
    languages =  []
    popularity = []
    for line in reader:
        counter.update(line['\ufeffProgramming language'].split(','))
    for item in counter:
        languages.extend(item[0])
        popularity.extend(item[1])
print(counter)
print(languages)
print(popularity)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'Java' : 2, 'C++' : 2, 'Python' : 1})
['P', 'J', 'C']
['y', 'a', '+']
```

Why is it that when I am trying to separate the values of the counter into two section i.e languages and popularity, I get a strange outcome?

Comment: What output were you expecting, exactly?

Comment: is `for item in counter.items()` not `for item in counter:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the [items](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) of counter:

```
for item in counter.items():
    languages.append(item[0])
    popularity.append(item[1])
```

Currently you are doing:

```
for item in counter:
    languages.extend(item[0])
    popularity.extend(item[1])
```

This iterates only over the keys, so when you do `item[0]` you get the first character of the key, this also applies to `item[1]`. Hence you get:

```
['P', 'J', 'C']
['y', 'a', '+']
```

The corresponding first and second letters of your keys. An alternative, perhaps more *pythonic*, is to use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
counter = {'Java' : 2, 'C++' : 2, 'Python' : 1}

languages, popularity = zip(*counter.items())

print(languages)
print(popularity)
```

**Output**

```
('Java', 'C++', 'Python')
(2, 2, 1)
```

**Update**

Notice that you should use append instead of extend. As pointed out by @SpghttCd.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Personally, I'd use `for k, v in counter.items()` to then be able to append simple variables instead of indexing a tuple, but this might be a matter of taste. I especially like the `zip` variant - thanks for recalling that.

Comment: One hint: in my tests, `extend` did _not_ work for `polularity` with the error message `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` - perhaps you should check that, too. However, IMO `append` would be the more meaningful list-method of choice here, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you are iterating over a dict, which means, that the iteration variable will hold each key.
So your languages is the list of all `items` (i.e. the keys) and the popularity is the list of all Counter[item] (i.e. the values):

Example:

```
d = {'Java' : 2, 'C++' : 2, 'Python' : 1}

languages = []
popularity = []
for item in d:
        languages.append(item)
        popularity.append(d[item])

# languages
# ['Java', 'C++', 'Python']

# popularity
# [2, 2, 1]
```